# UICollectionview not scroll to item by selectItem function IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I can't scroll to the Item with this function of collectionView

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 10 , section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
```

This CollectionView is Horizontal

Comment: Is frame of the collection view correct or it is bigger than the container (phone screen for instance)

Comment: it's inside a UIview of a scrollView, I mean UIScrollView has UIView and inside UIView is UIcollectionView, let me  send you the screenshot

Comment: If you swipe left/right can you get to the beginning and the end of the collection view

Comment: yes I can but by code can't scroll to selected item and i don't know why this happen :(

Comment: Try other options in: `UICollectionViewScrollPosition` and see if there is any difference

Comment: I think I make mistake In frame layouts maybe :((

Comment: this video show my problem , link: http://sendvid.com/tu5ol63h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently just selecting collection view item at indexPath, this will not scroll to item. **You need to scroll at position of selected item**. Add following method to scroll:

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 10 , section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 10 , section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: I did this function too, but not work yet :( - I want to re-layout ViewController maybe I make mistake in frame, but I don't know why this problem happens

Comment: Did you created `collectionView` programmatically ?.

Comment: No, I created in StoryBoard, My ControllerView has 3 UICollectionView

Comment: @omidshojaeyan , Then, For which collection view your are scrolling item position ? and Where your write the above code ?

Comment: I write all in ViewController. this link shows my problem on a short screen recorded , Link: http://sendvid.com/tu5ol63h

Answer (score -3):

Thank you, everyone. I solved with this code. my mistake code is `self.categoryItemsCollection.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.section, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)` just change the scrollPosition parametr to .centeredHorizontally `self.categoryItemsCollection.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.section, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)`

Comment: not the expected answer, but got to make my collection view not scroll while I set the selected index when scrolling is vertical, setting scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally cancels the scroll.